# What are risks associated with injection made by a non-sterile needle?

Tags: infection, blood, injections

On a regular vaccination, I've been handled by an unprofessional staff, who ( while preparing the injection needle) touched her hands 2 times to the injection needle (staff wore the gloves, but they were for sure non-sterile, due the fact that she was touching visitor's stuff with same gloves).

[image]

So, I have a generic medical question - what are the possible/worst risks associated when a person is shot with non-sterile (contaminated) injection needle, and what should be done by the victim after that fact?

Comment: She actually touched the needle itself? Not the plastic hub, but the metal part of the needle? I would refuse the injection in that scenario and demand that she replace the needle with a new, sterile one. She's not going to argue with you because she knows her supervisor will agree with you.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes, that was case - the metal part  (yeah,I live in a mid-developing country...) Unfortunately, I was too late to tell her to stop, because I was so surprised, before I realized that and believed my eyes, she already pulled the needle inside my arm. Moreover, even after that I said about it, and she & other colleagues attacked me that "they have experience and know medicine more than me". I left the clinic very angry and will always warn everyone about that place and such personnel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an exhaustive list, but a non-sterile puncture is

- a [risk of tetanus](https://www.cdc.gov/tetanus/about/causes-transmission.html) (infection with Clostridium tetani):

> The spores can get into the body through broken skin, usually through injuries from contaminated objects. Tetanus bacteria are more likely to infect certain breaks in the skin.  These include:
>
> Wounds contaminated with dirt, poop (feces), or spit (saliva)
> Wounds caused by an object puncturing the skin (puncture wounds), like a nail or needle.
>
> Tetanus bacteria can also infect the body through breaks in the skin caused by [...] Intramuscular injections (shots given in a muscle)

- if the needle was actually used on someone else... a substantially wider spectrum of [risks exist of various blood-borne illness](https://www.nhs.uk/common-health-questions/accidents-first-aid-and-treatments/what-should-i-do-if-i-injure-myself-with-a-used-needle/). Most of those probably aren't much risk via fomites, i.e. merely touching the needle, but hepatitis is not something I'd totally [exclude]as the virus[es] causing these can transmit through other bodily fluids and in some experimental settings can [persist](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24273176/) a surprisingly long time even in dried state.

Comment: IMHO the most likely complication is an injection abscess by some facultative pathogenic cutaneous germs like Staph. aureus and the likes, [examplary case report](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4969378/)

Comment: I would think monitoring the injection site for signs of infection it’s probably worth mentioning. And while it’s far from best practices, and worth rejecting injection from a non-sterile needle, it’s also probably not particularly high risk either way with an antibiotic solution likely available for the most common complications—which are probably less than a 50-50 shot of occurring in the first place.

Comment: @Narusan thanks for comment. Can you please turn that into answer? makes sense.

Comment: @t.todua I think that it’s more a clarification/continuation on Fizz’s already correct/solid answer, not really a stand-alone answer.